# Adding days to the Date portion of DateTime throws off the Time portion

Tags: apex, datetime, bug

So I'm having an issue in Apex with the Date's addDays function.  It seems that adding more than a certain amount of days throws off the time by one hour.  It all seems so arbitrary so I'm wondering if this is a known thing in Salesforce or not.

```
DateTime aDate = System.now();
System.debug(aDate);
DateTime adjustedDate = 
DateTime.newInstance(aDate.date().addDays(4), aDate.time());
```

System.debug(adjustedDate);

Running that in an execute anonymous box outputs the following:
**2019-03-05 17:44:28**
**2019-03-09 17:44:28**

That's all good.  The same date separated by four days and the same time.  Just as you'd expect.  But... adding five or more days causes behavior I can't wrap my head around.

```
DateTime aDate = System.now();
System.debug(aDate);
DateTime adjustedDate = 
DateTime.newInstance(aDate.date().addDays(5), aDate.time());
System.debug(adjustedDate);
```

This outputs the following:
**2019-03-05 17:46:08**
**2019-03-10 16:46:08**

It falls back by an hour.  Any idea why or is this a known thing?  I'm in central timezone so my time is actually -6 hours from the printed time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daylight saving time 2019 in central timezone will begin at

**2:00 AM on
Sunday, March 10**

and ends at

**2:00 AM on
Sunday, November 3**

All times are in Central Time.

:)

Comment: In other words, Daylight Saving Time begins in 5 days at this point in time. Which explains the discrepancy between adding 4 days and 5 days.

Comment: Wow.  I completely forgot about Daylight savings time. Thank you!

Comment: +1. Great observation on Daylight changes.